# Выводить null если в группе присутствует хотя бы одно значение null

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица вида

```
shipment     order      date_start
---------------------------------------------
shipment1    order1     01-01-2019
shipment1    order2     null
shipment2    order3     05-01-2019
shipment2    order4     02-01-2019
```

Как сделать выборку так, чтобы при присутствии хотя бы одного null в группе, выводился null.

Т.е. в запросе вида

```
select shipment, max(date_start) from table group by shipment;
```

надо вывести

```
shipment1    null
shipment2    05-02-2019
```

Comment: `select t1.shipment,
max( case when exists( select 1 from table t2 where t2.date_start is null and t1.shipment=t2.shipment ) then null  else t1.date_start end )
from table t1 group by t1.shipment`

Answer (score 6):

Думаю так:

```
with data (shipment, orderno, date_start) as (
    select 'shipment1', 'order1', date'2019-01-01' from dual union all
    select 'shipment1', 'order2', null             from dual union all
    select 'shipment2', 'order3', date'2019-01-05' from dual union all
    select 'shipment2', 'order4', date'2019-01-02' from dual 
)
select shipment, max (date_start) keep (dense_rank first order by date_start desc) maxdate
from data
group by shipment
;

SHIPMENT  MAXDATE                      
--------- -----------------------------
shipment1 null                             
shipment2 2019-01-05 00:00:00
```

Агрегатные функции с `KEEP` есть только в *Oracle* СУБД. Более стандартный запрос, который вернёт тот же результат:

```
select shipment, date_start maxdate
from (
    select 
        d.*, 
        row_number () over (partition by shipment order by date_start desc nulls first) rn
    from data d
)
where rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    shipment, 
    FIRST_VALUE(date_start) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY shipment 
              ORDER BY date_start DESC NULLS FIRST)
FROM table
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код CTE честно украден из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984010/229437) товарища [0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217579/0xdb).

Answer (score 1):

```
select shipment,case count(*) when count(date_start) then max(date_start) end 
from t group by shipment;
```